# Firestore query issue when comparing timestamp

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have data in Firestore and I am comparing time object in it.

When I query with other object like `"ref" and "title"` query return some data successfully, but with time its not returning anything.

[image]

```
String dateString = "9-26-2018";
```

I am converting this date to `timestamp` and passing in query:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(dateString);

DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date utcTime = new Date(df.format(date));

System.out.println("MyDates >>" +utcTime + " >> "+ timestamp.toDate());

CollectionReference ref = db.collection("news");
Query newsQuery = ref.whereEqualTo("time", utcTime );

mNewsList.clear();
newsQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        System.out.println("DocumentData >> " + task.getResult().size());
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            News news = document.toObject(News.class);
                            mNewsList.add(news);
                        }
                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        // stop animating Shimmer and hide the layout
                        mShimmerViewContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
                        mShimmerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error getting documents."+ task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

> What I am getting is `task.getResult().size() = 0`

So my question is how to compare timestamp in Firestore?

UPDATE >>  Date Output >>

```
MyDates >>Tue Sep 25 18:30:00 GMT+05:30 2018 >> Wed Sep 26 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2018
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting `task.getResult().size() = 0` because you are passing in your query to the `whereEqualTo()` method as the second argument a primitive `long` and not a `Date` object. In order to use Firestore Query's [whereEqualTo(String field, Object value)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method in a correct way, please convert the long value to a Date object before using it like this:

```
long time = 1538306225;
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(time);
Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
Query newsQuery = ref.whereEqualTo("time", date);
```

Comment: I followed the exact way that you have mentioned above, but it does not return any result. :( My issue exactly the same as this question. when i used whereEqual for other fields it works perfectly, but not for timestamp. Please help me :)

Comment: @IsuruBandara Without seeing the code that you are using, it's quite impossible to say what is wrong. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I found a solution. I had to multiple time*1000 otherwise it does not show any result :D.